# Is it best practice to nest IoC registrations and could this be causing issues with my EF woes?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have been tasked with finding out why we get an intermittent error in a WPF application that uses AutoFac to register an instance of an EF context. That EF context is registered as a Singleton which I was going to try and set as a thread safe registration to test a theory. The EF version is still Framework and not core.

The registration of the context is then used as part of the parameters of 3 other registrations and in a subsequent application it is nested 10 times, all of which are registered as Singleton as well. Something just doesn't seem right about that and I think that might be where the error is stemming. I had issues in another shop with EF Contexts in Core not properly dropping resources to come to find out that I was using "Using" where I shouldn't have been and the way that the registrations were created was problematic.

The error we are getting is System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException. The underlying issue is that the impersonator that is set up (homebrew hardcoded, nothing out of the box in AD or something) seems to drop the impersonated credentials and tries to access the database using the user's credentials instead of the application's. It seems as though that the context credentials have timed out or something.

I understand the purpose of the IoC containers but by no means an expert in the "under the hood" aspects of it, this just has a "smell" to me that may or may not be there.

```
builder.RegisterType<Context>().InstancePerLifetimeScope().WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
(pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(Context),
(pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<Context>())).SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(RepositoryService<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
(pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(Context),
(pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<Context>())).SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>().WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
(pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(Context),
(pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<Context>())).SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<LoginHistoryRepository>().As<ILoginHistoryRepository>().WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
(pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(Context),
(pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<Context>())).SingleInstance();
```

Just trying to be sure I am not crazy here. The "timeouts" range from 10 to 30+ minutes if the application sits "idle" for too long if that helps.

Weirdly enough I get "Access Denied" if I change those to "InstancePerLifetimeScope".

Comment: I don't use EF so I can't answer the underlying question, but it does seem weird that you've manually wired up the parameters like this when Autofac will look at the constructors and inject that automatically.

Comment: @TravisIllig Yeah that was my initial thought when I first saw this legacy code, in previous shops I would just have the dependencies done like you say, single registrations and that class has what it needs injected there.